# Non-convex objective function + (non-convex constraint function vs. convex constraint function)

Tags: soft-question, convex-optimization, non-convex-optimization, convexity-inequality, relaxations

In the optimization problem, both objective function and the constraint functions are non-convex. (topology optimization)
- objective function: force on structure
- constraint functions: material volumes
However, I can transform the non-convex constraint function to be convex. The modified constraint function is not the same in the function shape, but it has the same physical meaning in convergence.

I thought that it find better solutions with convex constraint function, but in my case, the problems with non-convex constraints find better solutions ('better' means the number of local optimum solutions with different initial values).

I think I can arrange the question as follow,
"Is it guarantee that I can find better solutions in the optimization problem has a non-convex objective function with convex constraint function than with non-convex constraint function? (assume the meaning of the convex/non-convex constraint functions are the same)"

Comment: If you change the problem and have found "better" solutions that didn't exist before, in what sense are the two problems equivalent? Does the solution to the convex problem help you solve the non-convex problem? Maybe an example would help clarify the question.

Comment: @TheoBendit the problems may not the same but assume that the meaning of the convex and non-convex constraints are the same.

Comment: "Meaning" is not a mathematical concept, it is a philosophical or psychological one.

Comment: @RobertIsrael It seems that I did not deliver the contents properly. The details are not important. My question is 'which one is better to find the (local) optimum solution: 1) non-convex objective function + non-convex constraint function, or 2) non-convex objective function + convex constraint function, or case by case?' Just I want to know that it is possible to prove mathematically.

Comment: It's impossible to judge.  Other things being equal, I'd prefer convex constraints.  But other things are not equal.